# how to stack arrays together when they have the same title

Tags: php, arrays

I am scraping a document and have 2 different arrays: the titles and the links. I am using array_push() to store each item in their own array. I scrape 2 different documents for the same arrays. I would like afterwards the 2 arrays to be compared and for any matching titles to have 2 different links associated with the same title. This way I can display

`title1: source 1, source 2`

`title2: source 1, source 2.`

is this possible?

Comment: Show your code will be quick to understand what you ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will combine your arrays into a **title** => **link** format, where link may be an array if multiple sources were found. This is a very simplistic approach, you could get more advanced by comparing case-insensitively and making sure that `$link` is only adding unique entries to the combined array.

```
$array1 = array_combine($titles1, $links1);
$array2 = array_combine($titles2, $links2);

foreach ($array2 as $title => $link) {
    if (isset($array1[$title])) {
        $array1[$title] = array($array1[$title], $link);
    } else {
        $array1[$title] = $link;
    }
}
```

Comment: exactly what i was trying to do, knew there had to be a way, just didnt know how!